# Class __init__ with dict mapping to either key or other_class(key)

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to deal with a kind of messy pydantic-based `__init__` , where I am mapping a nested JSON dict into a pydantic model. Example JSON:

```
{ 'a' : 1,
'b': {'z':100, 'y':200},
'c':datetime.date.today(),
'd' : {'hi':class_instance(), 'string':'something'}}
```

In my Pydantic model, keys 'b' and 'd' have their own Pydantic Models that need to be initialized.  In this particular case, I know I could 'hard-code' a lot of this, but the reality is far more complicated.

I am trying to think of a way to map this JSON to the `__dict__` of the pydantic model, where in the case there is a nested dict that the appropriate sub-pydantic model is initalized and returned.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: What you showed is **not** JSON, it is a Python dictionary. Aside from that your post is very confusing. You talk about some `__init__` that you never show, some Pydantic models that may or may not exist; the title seems entirely unrelated... If you want people to help you, try and ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 1) Describe the setup (typically classes/functions involved that are already given/unchangeable). 2) Show example input. 3) Show desired output. 4) Show what you tried and the incorrect output or errors you received.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whether you want to map your JSON to Pydantic model so you can have all your nested data as **models** or you want to represent it as nested dictionaries, without models in the structure. For a given instance `model` you will get the first option by calling `dict(model)` and the second by calling the [`model.dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Bar(BaseModel):
    z: int
    y: int

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Bar

foo = Foo(**{"a": 1, "b": {"z": 100, "y": 200}})

print(foo)  # Foo(a=1, b=Bar(z=100, y=200))
print(foo.dict())  # {'a': 1, 'b': {'z': 100, 'y': 200}}
print(dict(foo))  # {'a': 1, 'b': Bar(z=100, y=200)}
```